# Packed struct with bitfields. VC++ and GCC/CLANG differet code generation

Tags: c++, g++, visual-studio-2019

There is program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
struct A {
        uint32_t a;
        uint32_t b : 24;
        uint32_t c;
} __attribute((packed))__;

int main() {
        std::cout << sizeof(A) << std::endl;
}
```

and its for windows equivalent

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct A {
        uint32_t a;
        uint32_t b : 24;
        uint32_t c;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
int main() {
        std::cout << sizeof(A) << std::endl;
}
```

VC2019 compiled binary says 12
gcc12 and apple clang compiled binary says 11
I understand that #pragma and __attribute is compiler depended, but I wonder if there is any way to do it portable. (besides removing bitfield).
Is something in C++ standard I overlooked?

Comment: Bitfields are *always* going to be very compiler- and target-specific. Don't use them for any kind of portable code, or when you need to communicate with binary protocols.

Comment: Bitfields probably do not do what you think they do. The only thing C++ expects of them is that they behave like integers with the specified number of bits. It is not a specification for memory layout. For that you need to use one of the integer values and implement bit arithmetic your self (masking, shifting) etc. 
So make your b just an std::uint32_t and add some extra operations on your struct that handle the setters/getters for b

Comment: [cppreference on bitfields](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field), look for "implementation defined"